# Google Fonts Not Loading on Their Own Site

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, archlinux

I know this has come up dozens of times over the years, but I can't find anything relating to my problem in particular.

If I head over to https://fonts.google.com/ in Chrome, the fonts time out with these errors:

```
java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:121 Error: i
at Sd.f (rs=AE60u5dxhZ7D9xkmGMx3DX8X4TvBHXsNAw:190)
at eval (java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:154)
at e (java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:46)
at eval (java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:49) undefined
Ne.p.defer @ java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:48
g @ java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:154
Sd.f @ rs=AE60u5dxhZ7D9xkmGMx3DX8X4TvBHXsNAw:190
(anonymous) @ java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:154
e @ java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:46
(anonymous) @ java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:49
java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:121 Error: i
at Sd.f (rs=AE60u5dxhZ7D9xkmGMx3DX8X4TvBHXsNAw:190)
at eval (java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:154)
at e (java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:46)
at eval (java/com/google/fonts/directory/ui/angular_js.js:49) "Possibly unhandled 
rejection: {}"
```

It would be no big deal, but they also aren't loading in my project via the CDN.

**Points of Interest**

- I've seen answers pointing to a Firefox bug, but they work fine in Firefox for me.
- I'm on Arch Linux. The same thing happens in *google-chrome, google-chrome-beta, google-chrome-dev, and chromium*
- Manually deleting caches for those browsers didn't work.
- Emptying caches from the browser tools didin't work.
- Restoring default fontconfig didnt' work.
- The same version of chrome (64.0.3282.140) loads these fonts just fine in my Windows 10 guest on VirtualBox
- Material Icons are loading just fine, and I thought they came from the same repository.

I'm perplexed.

Comment: I have the exact same issue... also on linux :/

Comment: Have you tried changing your user-agent? I'm not sure how to in chrome, but if you use the firefox user agent and fonts work in chrome, then it's a google problem.

Comment: Thanks for that excellent suggestion! No luck, however.

Comment: I changed `Xft.rgba` from `rgba` to `rgb` in my `.Xdefaults`. Does that work? If so, I'll formally write an answer.

Comment: Mine is already set to rgb.

Comment: I have exactly the same, also on Arch Linux. I have had other web-font related issue, e.g. the Material Design icons not loading on CircleCI, and new mails not appearing as bold in the new GMail. Did you find an answer to it?

Comment: In all honesty, I gave up on this issue. Three weeks ago I took some time to dig into my font configuration (completely unrelated), and I just noticed they are working again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have Noto font install.
Removing it solved the problem for me